# Apache is not starting using Mamp in Windows 10?

Tags: php, apache, configuration, mamp

I am plannig to start a simple php application to do that I instaled Mamp because I worked with it before, it is good, but now I am facing a problem, as the title says, my Apache Server is not starting, it starts and then when MySql starts it stops, I did  not understand what was happening so I tried some solutions I found here in stackoverflow.

One of the solutions suggested that this is a problem in the latest version 4.1.1, so he provided a link to the previous version 4.1 and it is true because this problem was not there before, I took the exe file and installed it but I had the same problem, maybe Mamp version changing has helped him but did not worked for me.

The second solution is a solution that has been suggested by many people, and I think it is a solution, but I could not implement it and that's why I am here.
The solution says that changing the php version in the `Mamp - Preferences - php` to 7.2.14 instead of 7.3 solves the problem, I tried it but I get an error, Windows interface pops up and saying that something in not found, I did not get what was that, and googled it but I am still unable to understand what is missing and I feel like that nobody before me faced the problem x).
The message in french but here is what is saying :

> The processus starting point zend_wrong_parameter_count_error@@16 is
>   not found in the library of dynamic links.
>   C:/MAMP/bin/php/php.7.2.14/ext/php_gd2.dll

I think the message is clear, something is missing, and it is this file `php_gd2.dll`, I checked and it is true, but how am I going to add it correctly ?
I downloaded the file from a website and added it to my php7.14.2 folder but I get the same error.

Any help would be much appreciated, I wanted to start the app a month ago and faced this problem and then changed my plans just because of it and now I need to fix it to move on.

Comment: Even in 2020 MS has not come up with a working software management which has been standard on other systems for more than 20 years prevent such things.

Comment: @arkascha Yes, shame, I see a lot of people suffering from their installation problems, I installed XAMPP now

Comment: Why didn't you install Linux instead? Then you would not have such issues :-) No, seriously, I know that is possible, but not always the first option people chose.  Good luck.

Comment: Never used Linux, and I won't use it just to solve such problem

Comment: Sure, I can understand that. A typical situation: each single issue one faces does not hold enough pressure to finally make that step. All fine :-)

Comment: Thanks, Have a great day